# How to update more table rows at once using Laravel and Vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have **settings** table with 3 columns (id, property, content).
I have seeded some data into settings table and I want to update this table. I am filling some form where each input is presenting one row of the table **settings**. After submitting that form, I want my table to be updated...
For example, some of my property-content pairs (some of my inputs in this form) are:
background_image - 'image.jpg'
header - 'this is the header'

I am confused because I don't really know what should I send to backend and also I am not sure what should **endpoint** be...
I hope some of you can help me. If you need more questions, be free to ask me. Thanks in advance, and here is my code:

**SettingsController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\UpdateSettings;
use App\Http\Resources\SettingResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Setting;

class SettingController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $settings = Setting::all();

        return SettingResource::collection($settings);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(UpdateSettings $request, Setting $setting)
    {

        $setting->where('property', $request->property)
                ->update([ 'content' => $request->content ]);


        return new SettingResource($setting);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Settings.vue**

```
    <template>
    <div class="ml-4 container">
        <button @click="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Save Admin Settings</button>

        <div class="custom-file mt-3">
            <label for="backgroundImage" class="custom-file-label input">Add Background Image</label>
            <input id="backgroundImage" @input="errors.clear('background_image')" @change="uploadImageName" type="file" class="custom-file-input btn btn-primary"
                   style="background: #1d68a7">
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('background_image')">{{ errors.get('background_image') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="header">Header</label>
            <input :class="{'is-invalid' : errors.get('header')}" @input="errors.clear('header')" v-model="form.header" type="text" class="form-control input" id="header">
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('header')">{{ errors.get('header') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="videoOne">Video one</label>
            <textarea :class="{'is-invalid' : errors.get('video')}" @input="errors.clear('video')" v-model="form.video" type="text" class="form-control videoBox input" id="videoOne"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('video')">{{ errors.get('video') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                               @click="toggleBtn()"
                               v-model="form.active_video"
                               color="#82C7EB"
                               :sync="true"
                               :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <label for="sectionOneText">Section One Text</label>
            <editor
                @input="errors.clear('section_one')"
                v-model="form.section_one"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="sectionOneText"
            >
            </editor>
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('section_one')">{{ errors.get('section_one') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
            <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                           @click="toggleBtn()"
                           v-model="form.active_section_one"
                           color="#82C7EB"
                           :sync="true"
                           :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
            />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <label for="editableBoxContainer">Editable Box Container</label>
            <editor
                @input="errors.clear('editable_box')"
                v-model="form.editable_box"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="editableBoxContainer"
            >
            </editor>
            <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.get('editable_box')">{{ errors.get('editable_box') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
            <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                           @click="toggleBtn()"
                           v-model="form.active_editable_box"
                           color="#82C7EB"
                           :sync="true"
                           :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
            />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <label for="sectionTwoText">Section Two Text</label>
            <editor
                @input="errors.clear('section_two')"
                v-model="form.section_two"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="sectionTwoText"
            >
            </editor>
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('section_two')">{{ errors.get('section_two') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
            <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                           @click="toggleBtn()"
                           v-model="form.active_section_two"
                           color="#82C7EB"
                           :sync="true"
                           :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
            />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3">
            <label for="sectionThreeText">Section Three Text</label>
            <editor
                @input="errors.clear('section_three')"
                v-model="form.section_three"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="sectionThreeText"
            >
            </editor>
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('section_three')">{{ errors.get('section_three') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
            <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                           @click="toggleBtn()"
                           v-model="form.active_section_three"
                           color="#82C7EB"
                           :sync="true"
                           :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
            />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="videoTwo">Video two</label>
            <textarea :class="{'is-invalid' : errors.get('video_two')}" @input="errors.clear('video_two')" v-model="form.video_two" type="text" class="form-control videoBox input" id="videoTwo"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('video_two')">{{ errors.get('video_two') }}</span>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <toggle-button class="mt-2 toggleButton"
                               @click="toggleBtn()"
                               v-model="form.active_video_two"
                               color="#82C7EB"
                               :sync="true"
                               :labels="{checked: 'Active', unchecked: 'Deactive'}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="linkOne">Link One</label>
            <input :class="{'is-invalid' : errors.get('link_one')}" @input="errors.clear('link_one')" v-model="form.link_one" type="text" class="form-control input" id="linkOne">
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('link_one')">{{ errors.get('link_one') }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="linkTwo">Link Two</label>
            <input :class="{'is-invalid' : errors.get('link_two')}" @input="errors.clear('link_two')" v-model="form.link_two" type="text" class="form-control input" id="linkTwo">
            <span class="text-danger"  v-if="errors.get('link_two')">{{ errors.get('link_two') }}</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import {ToggleButton} from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
import Errors from "../helpers/Errors";
Vue.component('ToggleButton', ToggleButton)
export default {
    name: "Settings",
    components: {Editor},

    data() {
        return {
            errors: new Errors(),
            form: {
                background_image: '',
                header: '',
                video: '',
                active_video: null,
                section_one: '',
                active_section_one: null,
                editable_box: '',
                active_editable_box: null,
                section_two: '',
                active_section_two: null,
                section_three: '',
                active_section_three: null,
                video_two: '',
                active_video_two: null,
                link_one: '',
                link_two: '',
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    methods: {
        toggleBtn() {
            if (this.sectionTwotext) {
                this.sectionTwotext = false;
            } else {
                this.sectionTwotext = true;
            }
        },
        async submit() {
            try {
                const form = Object.assign({}, this.form);

                console.log(form);

                let result = Object.keys(form).map(function (key) {

                    return [key, form[key]];
                });
                console.log(result[0])

                result._method = 'PUT';

                for(let i=0; i<=15; i++) {
                    let objectResult = Object.assign({}, result[i]);
                    console.log('objectResult')
                    console.log(objectResult)
                    objectResult._method = 'PUT';
                     const {data} = await axios.post(`/api/setting/${i}`, objectResult);
                 }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
            }

        },
        uploadImageName() {
            let image = document.getElementById("backgroundImage");
            this.form.background_image = image.files[0].name;
            console.log(image.files[0].name);
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#saveBtn {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.input {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.videoBox {
    height: 300px;
}
.toggleButton {
    margin-left: auto;
}
</style>
```

My async Submit function is not OK, I was just trying something...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not clear are u talking how to upload image or file in vuejs to laravel .?

Comment: My table has 3 columns (id, property, content). 
I have 16 rows in that table... 
header => 'header',
background_image => 'image.jpg'
...
...
I have form with 16 inputs. The first one is upload button. The second one is header input, the third one is another input... I just need this image name, and also those inputs as strings because I save in database everything as string. 
So, when I fill every of these 16 inputs, I press SUBMIT and it should find certain propery and replace the content in that row with inputed value... Is it better now? I hope so... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider having a single `endpoint` on your `api` where you submit the entire form.

**api.php**

Create a route that we can submit our `axios` request to:

```
Route::put('/settings', 'Api\SettingController@update')->name('api.settings.update');
```

Note that I have namespaced the `controller` as you will likely have a `web` and `api` version of this controller. Mixing your `api` and `web` actions in a single controller is not advisable.

**web.php**

This is a standard `web` route which will display a `blade` view containing the `vue` component. We pass through the settings which will then be passed to the `Settings.vue` component as a `prop`.

```
Route::get('/settings', 'SettingController@edit')->name('settings.edit');
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<settings :settings="{{ $settings }}"></settings>
```

**Settings.vue**

```
axios.put('/api/settings', {
  header: this.form.header,
  background_image: this.form.background_image
  ... other fields to be submitted
})
.then(success => {
  console.log(success);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**SettingController.php**

```
public function edit()
{
  return view('settings.edit', ['settings' => Setting::all()]);
}
```

**Api\SettingController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  $validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
    [
      'header' => ['required', 'string'],
      'background_image' => ['required', 'string']
      ... other fields to be validated
    ]
  );

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
  }

  foreach ($validator->validated() as $property => $content) {
    Setting::where('property', $property)->update(['content' => $content]);
  }

  return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
}
```

You might want to consider splitting settings into groups and submitting groups rather than the entire form, or submitting each setting individually (where it makes sense to do so).

Comment: Thanks! I have a little bit different "style" of coding this, but You gave me some ideas! 
Thanks a lot!